# JTable Not Updating Data

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

For some reason, nothing changes about this JTable when this is called (this method updates the JTable after a user submits an SQL query).

Givens:
The dataVector and columnNamesVector are verified to be populated correctly.
JTable is a private class variable.

```
private void updateData() {
    updateDataVariables();
    table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common beginner's fallacy to confuse objects with reference variables, but you need to understand that they are quite distinct. When you call this:

```
table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector) {.....
```

You are creating a new JTable object and having the table variable refer to it, but **this has no effect on the JTable *object* that is displayed by the GUI**, the one that the table variable was referring to previously. So you're changing the property of the reference variable, but leaving the original object unchanged.

The solution:  You should not be creating a new JTable but rather you should be creating a new TableModel and then place that TableModel into the existing and visualized JTable. You can change a table's model by calling `setModel(newModel)` on it.

Edit: or as wolfcastle noted you could update the existing TableModel rather than create one anew.

Comment: or just update your model instead of creating a new one every time

Comment: Yes, but how do I go about converting my dataVector and columnNamesVector into TableModel and ColumnNamesModel respectively? This is the only format in which I have the data in. Is there some way to convert that?

Comment: @JoeBabcock: check out the DefaultTableModel API as that may have the constructors and methods that you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell JTable that the data in model was updated with firing appropriate event.

See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange)

Comment: This won't help since the original JTable, the one displayed in the GUI is unaffected.